# Styling Background in Blazor page/component

Tags: css, raspberry-pi, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor app, right now, a default "/" page and one called "/rtdpage"

No problem getting the background on the "/" to black

```
html, body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Problem is that I'm looking to get the /rtdpage styled with a 
 background-color:rgb(189, 191, 193);

I can't figure out how to apply a class to the page/app/body, or get the background to change
Tried:

```
@page "/rtdpage"

<style>
    background-color:rgb(189, 191, 193);
</style>

<h1>This is the RTD page</h1>

@code {}
```

Also dried putting a `<div>` around  and setting it to 100% width and 100% height, but still leaves most of the page black

Obviously, I'm a newbie at this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Second try,

You can create 2 components ;

YellowComp

```
@page "/Yellow"

<style>
    body {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
</style>

<h3>YellowBackground</h3>

@code {

}
```

BlueComp

```
@page "/Blue"

<style>
    body {
        background-color: blue;
    }
</style>

<h3>BlueBackground</h3>

@code {

}
```

When you then go these pages; you see this;

[image: YellowComp]

[image: BlueComp]

In case you would like to have a complete blue or yellow page , without anything else, you need to change the MainLayout.razor component to this :

```
<div class="main">
     <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That I have no problem with - I want the WHOLE PAGE grey (and there is another one that will be blue, and another dark green, and another bright green....)

Comment: So, the page is now:
```@page "/rtdpage"

<style>
    body{
    background-color:rgb(189, 191, 193);
    }
</style>


<h1>This is the RTD page</h1>

@code {}```

and the 
mainlayout is
```@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="main">
 
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>```
and I still get:
The <h1> with the grey background (yes at the top of page), but the entire lower part of the the screen is still black

Answer (score 0):

You can add background color with `inline CSS` in **main class** the color as per your choice like this in MainLayout.razor.

```
div class="main" style="background-color: #F8F9FB"
```